# Google Maps Api, GeoJson and InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, geojson

Can someone tell me why the InfoWindow doesn't appear at first click?
After the first click it always works fine...

I'm just loading data from a geojson file and try to adding a click event.

There are some problems anchoring an infowindow to a MVCObject.

```
var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
anchor.setValues({//position of the point
    position:event.latLng,
    anchorPoint:new google.maps.Point(0,-40)});

infoWindow.open(map, anchor);
```

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ajcL2y9p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `var infoWindow` from inside the `click` listener and it works fine.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajcL2y9p/1/)

Like this:

```
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "",
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
    });
    // When the user clicks, set 'isColorful', changing the color of the letters.
    map.data.addListener('click', function (event) {

        event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);



        infoWindow.setContent('<div>test</div>');

        var anchor = new google.maps.MVCObject();
        anchor.setValues({ //position of the point
            position: event.latLng,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -40)
        });

        infoWindow.open(map, anchor);

    });
```

`infoWindow` was only being initialized in the first click. If you place it outside you initialize it and then only set the content.

Answer (score 0):

initialize your your infowindow variable out side the function, some where in the initmap(); function.

hope this will help you.